# Boost.Python Link Error with Python3 and virtualenv

Tags: boost-python, clang++

I got the following error when I tried to compile `.cpp` file with `clang++`.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

I set up `Python` and `boost-python` as follows.

**Python**

I installed Python 3.6.0 using `pyenv-virtualenv` (via `homebrew`)

**Boost-Python**

I used `homebrew` in Python 3 environment.

```
$ source activate py36    
$ brew install boost-python --with-python3 --without-python
```

**~/.bash_profile**

My `~/.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="/usr/local/var/pyenv"
export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/include/python3.6m/"
if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi
if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" ; fi
```

---

**Test cpp**

This is the file I tried to compile and failed (saved as `test.cpp`).

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB    
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

char const* say(){
  return "hello, world";
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( hello ){

  boost::python::def( "say", say );

}
```

---

**makefile**

```
CC = clang++
INCLUDE = -I`python -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import *; print(get_python_inc())’`
BOOST = -lboost_python3.6 -lboost_serialization
FMATH =  -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-operator-names -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -march=native
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/lib -O3
CFLAGS_SO = -shared -fPIC -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/lib -O3 
LINK = -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.64.0/lib/

install: 
    $(CC) test.cpp -o hello.so $(INCLUDE) $(BOOST) $(LINK) $(FMATH) $(CFLAGS_SO)
```

---

**Error**

`make install` returns this error.

```
clang++ test.cpp -o hello.so -I`python -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import *; print(get_python_inc())’` -lboost_python3.6 -lboost_serialization -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.64.0/lib/ -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-operator-names -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -march=native -shared -fPIC -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/lib -O3  -v
/bin/sh: command substitution: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: command substitution: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang -cc1 version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "-lboost_python3.6"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 /usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/include/python3.6m
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o hello.so -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.64.0/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/rm/qv81g4ss29j_gv1b366rl2080000gp/T/test-16790a.o -lboost_serialization -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

<LINES ARE OMITTED>

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [install] Error 1
```